# How it is possible to make bad audio amp?

Tags: operational-amplifier

After discovering how great op amps are, and that some extremely good ones--especially at low power levels--are available at reasonable prices, I wonder why all audio amplifiers, big or small, don't achieve excellent performance by simply combining a good small-signal op amp with a simple output stage.

I mean, with opamp there is no need to worry about all these bias voltages & temperature stability, just stick opamp and any unmatched darlington transistors, and you are good to go.

Any pitfalls?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The use of opamps in amplifiers can drastically simplify their design, but opamps aren't perfect. If they would have infinite amplification over their full bandwidth they would tend to **oscillate**, so they are internally compensated, which limits their bandwidth. A limited bandwidth makes the amplifier prone to **Transient Intermodulation Distortion** (TIM), a type of distortion much more annoying than harmonic distortion (HD).

> *The reason only HD is published, and TIM never is, is that it's much easier to get good-looking HD figures. Who wouldn't be impressed by a figure like 0.01% harmonic distortion? Most customers don't realize that this figure is totally irrelevant because the total system's distortion is for the most part determined by the speakers, which easily add a few percent distortion.*

The power stage isn't without its problems either. Class A amplifiers are hardly used because of their low efficiency. Class B or AB amplifiers have a **crossover distortion** where one transistor takes over from the other. This is a non-linear distortion <s>which *can't be compensated by feedback*. May not be true. If someone can enlighten here I'd love to hear it.</s>.

A final quote on opamps:

> *"There is no such thing as an unconditionally stable op amp unless it lies on the table with power disconnected"* [[1](http://www.intersil.com/data/an/an9415.pdf)]

---

**Further reading**
[1] Intersil appnote AN9415: [Feedback, Op Amps and Compensation](http://www.intersil.com/data/an/an9415.pdf)

Comment: Why do you believe that crossover distortion can't be be compensated by feedback?

Comment: @Bitrex - I remember that's what I learned, though I forgot the reasoning behind the claim. Just stuck in my mind.

Comment: Crossover distortion is greatly improved by feedback, but nothing is ever perfect.  You say TIM is much more annoying than THD, but your quote doesn't say anything about it.  Can you elaborate on this point?

Comment: @endolith - No. :-) These things are very subjective, and measured values are not always an indication of user experience. Fact is that rather high levels of THD, in the order of 1 %, aren't noticeable for most people, and TIM seems to be noticed sooner at the same % than THD. I recall reading a report on this, but that was in my Philips Audio period, before the internet even, and I don't have the document here.

Comment: @stevenvh: Well, a THD of x% can be inaudible if it's all 2rd harmonic clipping distortion, while being very audible if it's 15th harmonic crossover distortion.  A THD number alone isn't sufficient to describe the audibility, but that doesn't mean the audibility is somehow immeasurable.  But where is that quote from, at least?  Google can't find it.

Comment: @endolith - THD is (output signal - input signal)/(input signal), so it should include *all* harmonics. Hence the "T", for total. The input signal will usually be a 1 kHz sine. About the quote: I'm on a brand new PC, and Copernic is still indexing, only 168 000 files done (there are 1.2 million files and folders on my PC, among which 34 000 PDF documents). Copernic doesn't find it yet either :-(, sorry.

Comment: @stevenvh: Yes, a 1 kHz sine wave with a 10 kHz distortion component is more audible than a 1 kHz sine wave with a 2 kHz distortion component at the same level, because the nearby harmonic is masked, but the far away harmonic is not.  Crossover distortion is especially audible because the frequency of the harmonics *change* as the signal level changes, creating filter sweeping sounds.  With clipping distortion, only the level of the harmonics changes as the signal level changes.

Comment: @endolith - But cross-over distortion also creates harmonics of the sine, and in TIM the distortion are not harmonics of the base signals (they're sum and difference frequencies), which may be the reason why we're more sensitive to them.

Comment: @stevenvh: The nearby 2 kHz harmonic is [masked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auditory_masking) by the 1 kHz tone, while the more distant 10 kHz harmonic is not.  TIM could also be masked, depending on where it appears in the spectrum.

Comment: @endolith - I see in your profile that you're also in audio. What kind? At Philips I worked on high-end consumer, like the first consumer digital speaker. (Well, it was still 2400 dollar a pair...)

Comment: There is also the view that TIM is a myth that was believed by some audiophools in the 70's in connection with the evils of global negative feedback. TIM has to do with the idea that there are multiple echoes in the amplifier, due to multiple round trips around the feedback loop. This is something which supposedly affects musical signals, but is invisible under testing with sinusoidals.

Comment: E.g. see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermodulation#Intermodulation_in_audio_applications). *"Transient intermodulation distortion, or TIM, occurs in amplifiers that employ negative feedback when signal delays make the amplifier incapable of correcting distortion when exposed to fast, transient signals."* (marked dubious)  The idea is that there are signals in ordinary audio (well within frequency specs of the amplifier) for which this can happen, and people with golden ears can hear it.

Comment: If an amplifier is fed a single periodic wave of almost any shape, even distortion which is noticeable will generally not be overly objectionable, since it wouldn't contain any sound that wasn't a multiple of 1000Hz.  Indeed, many kinds of distortion would be aesthetically pleasing.  If, however, the amplifier were fed a 1000Hz wave and a 1260Hz wave simultaneously (a musical interval of a major third)...

Comment: ...distortion could cause the amplifier's output could contain any frequency which was the sum or difference of some multiple of 1000Hz and some multiple of 1260Hz.  For example, it would likely contain 260Hz (1260-1000), 2260 (1260+1000), 520Hz (2*1260-2*1000), 740Hz (2*1000-1260), 480hz (3*1000-2*1260), and many other frequencies besides.  Such frequencies are much more perceptible than those which are related to the original frequencies.

Comment: Incidentally, "power chords" on a guitar involve playing three strings in a frequency ratio very close to 2:3:4.  This is done to exploit distortion in an amplifier which will generate sum and difference frequencies which are all multiples of a pitch an octave below the lowest note played.  The net effect is that a power chord won't sound like a chord, but will instead sound like a lower note than the guitar could otherwise play.

Answer (score 7):

Interesting question - the answer (well *my* answer) is you can make a great audio amp this way. You would still have to pay some attention to the output stage, and overall design, but the use of opamps is no problem (and very common nowadays for basic, cheap amplifiers with good performance)
Although opamps are convenient tools and there are some excellent modern ones available, there are certainly still plenty of ways you can use them to achieve a poor result if you don't pay attention to the details.

This doesn't mean people will buy it though, and designers know this, so you still get high end valve based "Hi-Fi" amps costing >£2000 with 2% THD. You could maybe say the intention *was* to make a "bad" amplifier here as (ironically) it will make more money - unfortunately "great" means a lot of different things to a lot of different people.
You have some in the subjectivist camp that have basically decided the human ear is more accurate than any measurement tool, and can hear things none of them can see. So they can always say "Yes, your THD+n is indeed <0.001% from 20Hz-20kHz but you are not allowing for unmeasurable effect x with your design, and this is why it does not sound good to the ear"

If the desire for technical perfection were all that mattered then things like oxygen free cables costing hundreds would never get to market :-)

I think you may want to read Douglas Self's "Small Signal Audio Design" and "Audio Power Amplifier Design Handbook"
I have found him to be quite an authority on such matters. His books discuss the use of both opamps and discrete transistors. He weighs up the strengths/weaknesses which includes plenty of real life test data, and gives examples where you can obtain better performance with discrete transistors.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, in consumer electronics, it is common for low to medium power audio amplifiers to be entirely on a chip, nicknamed "chip amp".

One issue is that most of those cheap op-amps you allude to do not have a sufficiently wide voltage swing to drive an output stage which itself has no voltage gain. If an op-amp operates on +/-15V max, and we put a power stage after that, the output swing is still limited to +/-15V. There are op-amps that run on significantly higher voltages, but they get expensive.

Adding more voltage gain after the op-amp, such that the gain is enclosed in the global feedback loop, is risky and negates some of the space and cost saving benefit since then there is more complexity expressed in discrete components than just an output stage.

Nevertheless this is in fact sometimes done. For instance take a look at the [Marshall 8008](http://elektrotanya.com/PREVIEWS/63463243/23432455/marshall/marshall_rackmount_2x80w_8008.pdf_1.png) rackmount guitar amplifier. An op-amp drives an additional voltage amplification stage followed by an output stage. The VAS is interesting: it uses a pair of complementary transistors in common base, with bases tied to the +/-15V rails respectively. The feedback is taken right from the output stage so the extra gain is included in the feedback loop. Though the op-amp is internally compensated, this bolted-on VAS has its own compensation in the form of C15 and C17. The full open-loop gain of the op-amp is not used, since it has a local feedback via R3, and R45 also seems to play a role in providing a more local feedback path within the global one.

In summary, if the output voltage swing is within the range of a typical op-amp (or even beyond), there is no advantage in using an op-amp, since you can use a chip amp like an LM3886. Yet, using op-amps as the feedback summing point, with a discrete output stage, is not unheard of.

Answer (score 1):

There are the drive requirements of the output stage to keep in mind as well.  An amplifier rated for 100 watts average output power into an 8 ohm load, using a standard emitter-follower output stage, will require a swing of about +/- 40 volts peak to peak from the driver stage.  Opamps that can output these 'high' voltages are significantly more expensive than ordinary audio op amps.  In addition, there is still the issue of biasing the output properly and ensuring the biasing is temperature-stable; using an opamp as the driver does not magically solve this problem.

There are ways to use discrete transistors in the driver and output stages, along with associated biasing circuitry, and use an opamp as the driver, such as the applications note 
[here.](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snoa600a/snoa600a.pdf)  These circuits seem to be primarily for high-speed applications, however, and what advantage they might have for hi-fi audio (where stated goal is usually to have as few gain stages as possible, and make each of them as linear as possible *prior* to feedback being applied) is unclear.